# Unreal Engine 4 Setup problems

Tags: c#, mono, unreal-engine4

I am trying to run the **Unreal Engine-4** setup on **Ubuntu 14.04** but when running the command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential mono-gmcs mono-xbuild mono-dmcs libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil libmono-system-management4.0-cil libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil cmake dos2unix clang-3.5 libfreetype6-dev libgtk-3-dev libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil xdg-user-dirs
```

I am running into an error saying

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>       mono-gmcs : Depends: mono-mcs (= 3.12.1-0xamarin1) but 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1 is to be installed
>       E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any clues on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

```
but 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1 is to be installed
```

It appears you are using Mono 3.x install instructions for Unreal Engine-4's setup.

In Mono 4.x, the gmcs compiler (a shell script to docs/mcs) has been dropped as support for only 4.x+ frameworks are supplied by the default installer.

Remove the "mono-gmcs" from your *apt-get install* list, and try again. I am not sure if anything is in Unreal 4 is dependent on a Mono 3.x install or if Mono 4.x will work...

You can alway pin your Mono version to 3.12.1. Remove:

```
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main
```

from "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list" and add:

```
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy/snapshots/3.12.0 main" 
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-libtiff-compat main"
```

Then you can:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After that, try your Unreal Engine-4 setup routine again and the Mono version will match the setup steps on Unreal's web site.